# Installing apache2 ssl - ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl

I need to install a ssl in my apache2 ubuntu, and do not know what I'm wrong, but the fact is that I do not get ...
I have the relevant files: one .key file and two .crt files.
At first, when editing the apache2 configuration file to add corresponding to ssl virtualhost; to restart apache, I returned the error: key values ​​mismatch.
Therefore, I ran the following commands to check the keys:

```
openssl x509 -in -noout -modulus your_domain_com.crt | openssl md5
openssl rsa -in -noout -modulus your_domain_com.key | openssl md5
```

My mistake was that I was not taking the correct .crt file.
After solving this error, now the certificate appears to be installed correctly, but when I go to the url:

https://midominio.com

The browser tells me that the certificate is wrong: bad address error. I see the details of the certificate, and it turns out that the domain for which the certificate is issued, it's a different domain! ... And not my domain ... So I check the certificate in my windows system ( my laptop ), and it says that the domain for which the certificate is issued, is the correct domain...

What's going on? Any help?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Most likely apache is loading the default cert for the domain in question, and not the one you have added. Could paste us your virtual host config for that domain?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, three year old question with no answer.  I'm going to guess you got an answer since the website now works.  In case anyone comes back to this question, here's what happened:

The certificate that you created is what's called a "self-signed certificate".  In this scenerio, you are creating a certificate that your browser does not trust.  There are two ways to fix this:

- Add the certificate to your browser.  This fixes it for your installation of your browser, but anyone else visiting your site will get the same error.  This is fine if you're running your own site for your own people where distributing the certificate is simple and easy, but terrible if you are trying to get the public to visit your site.
- Have your certificate signed by a trusted CA or use [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Lastly, you mentioned that the browser is saying that there is a domain mismatch.  This often occurs when your certificate does not have the full domain name in it's subject field OR you are using a certificate issued for different domain.  Both require new certificates to fix.

If the subject field is incorrect, make sure you are typing in the full domain when creating your CSR, i.e. `midominio.com`.  Keep in mind that this certificate will NOT be valid for any subdomains like `www.midominio.com` or `help.midominio.com`.

For that, you will need to update your CSR to include [Subject Alternative Names](http://wiki.cacert.org/FAQ/subjectAltName).